# MDX query for hierarchical report using hiearchical and flat dimension

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube

My goal is to get a grouped report based on a MDX query on a OLAP cube.
The report should be grouped on a hierarchical dimension ***Location*** and a flat dimension ***Category***.
As a newbie I struggle to write a correct MDX query to get the expected result:

- **Europe** (Location)__________________________ Total: 84

  - **Switzerland** (Location)___________________ Total: 64

    - **Bern** (Location)_____________________ Total: 39

      - ***shoes*** (Category)________________ Total: 14
      - ***tshirts*** (Category)________________ Total: 13
      - ***trousers*** (Category)______________ Total: 12
    - **Zurich** (Location)____________________ Total: 25

      - ***shoes*** (Category)________________ Total: 15
      - ***tshirts*** (Category)________________ Total: 10
  - **Germany** (Location)_____________________ Total: 20

    - **Berlin** (Location)____________________ Total: 5

      - ***shoes*** (Category)________________ Total: 5
    - **Bonn** (Location)_____________________ Total: 15

      - ***tshirts*** (Category)________________ Total: 15
- **Australia** (Location)_________________________ Total: 30

  - **Sidney** (Location)_______________________ Total: 30

    - ***tshirts*** (Category)___________________ Total: 20
    - ***trousers*** (Category)__________________ Total: 10

I know T-SQL syntax but MDX is completely new to me. Any samples and ideas how to write the query appreciated!

Comment: what mdx have you tried?

Comment: this question is effectively parallel to in sql how do I specify a column and row in the following `SELECT * FROM` - have you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can get you started:

```
select HIERARCHIZE(Location.Continent-Country-City.MEMBERS) 
       * Category.Category.MEMBERS ON 1,
Measures.[Total] ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: Thanks! The result is almost what I need. Just wonder if it is by design that the ***Category*** groups will be repeated on all ***Location*** levels? Is there a way to have the ***Category*** groups just on the lowest ***Location*** Levels?

Comment: It certainly can be achieved, but there is no easy way to do it. I would rather handle that in the front end/reporting services.

Comment: @SouravA nice to give extra info - but why bother with `HIERARCHIZE(` ?

Comment: Some reporting tools, I heard don't keep the hierarchy intact. Just a precaution. Moreover it was used yesterday on another question at SO by #1 MDX guru here ;=)

Comment: @SouravA try this it is a little bit more challenging (!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549177/account-for-tied-ranks

Comment: @whytheq 2 questions. How do you end up with these blogs? What kind of work do you do? ;)

Comment: @SouravA we have about 20 cubes  - they are about 5 years old so quite mature. I just query the cubes and my colleagues develop them.