# Account for tied ranks

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm using the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [myset] AS 
    Order
    (
      {
          [Customer].[Country].[Country].MEMBERS
        * 
          [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
      }
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,ASC
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[rank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      (
        [Customer].[Country].CurrentMember
       ,[Customer].[Customer].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[myset]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[newrank] AS 
    IIF
    (
        [myset].Item(
        [Measures].[rank] - 1).Item(0).Name
      <> 
        [myset].Item(
        [Measures].[rank] - 2).Item(0).Name
     ,1
     ,
      ([myset].Item([Measures].[rank] - 2),[Measures].[newrank]) + 1
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[rank]
   ,[Measures].[newrank]
  } ON 0
 ,[myset] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It is the work of Amish Shah: http://blog.sqltechie.com/2010/03/rank-with-partitioning-mdx.html

Currently it does not give tuples that have the same value the same rank e.g. if x has an Internet Sales Amount of 10 and y also has 10, in the above they will not have the same rank.

Can the above be changed so that if they have the same value then they have the same value for `[Measures].[rank]` - and also the same value for `[Measures].[newrank]`?

(adding a third argument into the definition of `[Measures].[rank]` doesn't seem like a possible route to proceed as the Rank function then goes into cel-by-cell calculation mode)

Comment: Upvoted for the sheer challenge it presented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using recursive calculated members like so -

```
WITH 
  SET [myset] AS 
    Order
    (
      {
          [Customer].[Country].[Country].MEMBERS
        * 
          [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
      }
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,ASC
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[myrank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      (
        [Customer].[Country].CurrentMember
       ,[Customer].[Customer].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[myset]
    ) 


member prevmembervalue as 
(myset.item(myRank - 2), [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

member currentmembervalue as
(myset.item(myRank - 1), [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

MEMBER greaterthanprev as
iif(currentmembervalue > prevmembervalue, 1, 0)

member rankActual as
iif
(
 prevmembervalue = null, 1,
 iif(currentmembervalue > prevmembervalue,
  (myset.item(myRank - 2), rankActual) + 1,
  (myset.item(myRank - 2), rankActual)
 )
 )

select myset on 1,
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], rankActual, myRank}
on 0
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

The measures `greaterthanprev`, `currentmembervalue` and `prevmembervalue` are actually not needed. Added them here just for some added clarification on the process.

Comment: I think this is very similar to the script I ended up using but yours might go a little wrong if say every value for the customers of the second country in the list is less than every value for all the customers of the first country?

Comment: Pls enlighten me. I cant think of how it may go wrong.

Comment: you dropped the comparison of `.Name` which is the logic that ensures the ranking is partitioned.

Comment: Yes I didnt focus on the partition bit.

Comment: maybe we can insert the name logic into your definition of `rankActual` ?

Comment: whytheq - I don't see the point in further improving my answer if you already got it. Anyway, it is close to what you needed. Maybe you could instead share what you came up with you so that it could help others. Thanks for a good mdx challenge though.

Comment: (was this not an interesting question?)

Comment: It was one of the most grilling questions here, sir! I didnt further work on it because, i have already derived the satisfaction of working on a toughie :)